# Saving Highscore with PlayerPrefs, then moving it to next scene (GameOver Screen)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have a game that involves destroying falling clocks in under a minute to beat the highscore. I currently have a script that keeps track of the score when a clock is hit. I'm attempting to display the highscore with this screen and save it with PlayerPrefs. While it will update the current score when a clock is it, it will not update the existing highscore text or save it upon starting the program again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject explosionEffect;
public Rigidbody2D Clock;
public AudioClip pickupSound;
AudioSource audioSource;
public Text Score;
public Text highscore;
int Amount = 0;

public float SpeedUp = 1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    {
        if (other.tag == "Clock")
        {
            Destroy(Instantiate(explosionEffect.gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation), 5f);
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound, 1F);
            Amount++;
            Score.text = Amount.ToString() + " Clocks" ;

//Code of concern.
                if (Amount > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore", 0))
                {
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", Amount);
                    highscore.text = "Highscore: " + Amount.ToString();
                    PlayerPrefs.Save();
                    Debug.Log("HS");
                }
//Speeds up the clocks when hit, until a limit is met.
                if (Clock.velocity.y >= -30)
                {
                    Clock.velocity += Vector2.down * SpeedUp;
                    Debug.Log("Speed is now " + Clock.velocity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also trying to figure out how to transfer that information over to a Gameover Scene. I'm not sure if I should rely on PlayerPrefs (if that can do the job, I don't know) or look into json to do that.

Comment: You are using **PlayerPrefs.GetInt**, however you are not assigning it to a value to display. Check out the api: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html

Comment: Looks like a problem with how it's set up in the editor rather than a code problem. Your code looks like it should work.